# hiding and removing white space of header in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, header, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm working on an **ssrs** report. I can hide the header on the last page with

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages - 1 or Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages ,true,false)
```

This works, but after hiding the header controls the header white space is still showing on the last page. How can I remove the white space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hiding the controls on that expression so even if the controls are hidden then also the header is there. So that header is still occupying the white space. You can not hide header or remove that whitespace(As far as I know) but there is another approach you can try.

Add your header content on the reports main body and set the visibility expression there.

There is one catch though you can not access the PageNumber directly in the report body for that you need to  Create functions in the code under the report properties:

Page Number:

```
Function PageNumber() As String    
   Return Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber    
End Function
```

Total Pages:

```
Function TotalPages() As String   
   Return Me.Report.Globals!TotalPages    
End Function
```

Comment: ya, i accept this because i tried before , but the header will come on each page? based on whenever increasing the content in body, my requirement is to show the header on each page while increasing my content portion , that's why i'm trying to do like is there any other way.

Comment: No there is no other way to remove the header white spaces because it renders the header just sets its control to the visible false so white space is going to stay there.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you, can you give me a suggestion for header if i put inside  body means that should be maintain on each page while body content increasing.what i need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by Body Content increasing ?

Comment: if i gave multiple records in tablix means that will possible to increase right ? in that case i need to maintain the page header.

Comment: The tab-lix will automatically adjust its height and expand as it needs. But repeating the tablix on each page is little trickier.

Comment: ok can you please explain that. in that case only i want to maintain the page header on each page it should be based on tablix

Comment: You need to ask that as different question but before that google it. It has lots of resources if you just google.