# How to remove Page Header White Space in SSRS report for pages 2..x

Tags: reporting-services, removing-whitespace

We are trying to remove the white space taken up by the Page Header on every subsequent page after page 1.  We don't have blank pages, just white space taken up by the header.  It also doesn't seem to matter whether we send it directly to the printer or export it to a PDF.

1. On the Report section, we have set ConsumeContainerWhitespace = True.
2. On the Page Header section, we have PrintOnFirstPage = True
   and PrintOnLastPage = False.  Too bad there's not a
   PrintOnlyOnFirstPage option!
3. We have two Rectangles on the Page Header section encompassing all of our header fields, and we've tried setting the Hidden property of these
   rectangles to be:
   IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 1, False,True).
4. We have several Text Box fields on the Page Header inside both rectangles.  We are turning the visibility attribute of these Text Box fields either on/off depending on whether there's data present in the accompanying data field, e.g. =IIF(Len(First(Fields!SpecialOrderId.Value, "PurchPurchaseOrdersDS")) = 0, True, False).

I've tried the suggestion about putting the header code in the body and programmatically hiding it, but I'm getting this error:
\SSRS Reports\Reports\PurchPurchaseOrder : error AX3026: : PageNumber is invalid.  InvalidIdentifier

THECODE:

```
Public Function PageNumber() As String  
    Return Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber    
End Function
```

CALLING IT:

```
=IIF(Code.PageNumber() = "1", False,True)
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274855/hiding-and-removing-white-space-of-header-in-ssrs-report

Comment: The alternative is to add your page header content in the Body of the report.. remove page header and then set the visibility of the "header" content based on page number.

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I'm getting an error stating that the Visibility.Hidden expression for the rectangle refers to the global variable PageNumber of TotalPages.  These global variables can be used only in the page header and page footer.

Comment: use the function on the first link in the comment to get the page numbers and total pages. you cannot directly access the variable outside of header and footer

Comment: I must be doing something wrong as it is stating:  PageNo is invalid.  InvalidIdentifier.    I have: Public Function PageNo() As String   
   Return Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber    
End Function               And in my Rectangle I have:  =IIF(Code.PageNo() = "1", False,True)      I've also tried Int on the function and the rectangle code.

Comment: Did you add the function codes to the report property code window? Check your call name..  How are you calling the code? you should be using the following expression on your report body =code.PageNumber() for the page number and =code.TotalPages() to get the total number of pages! I did the same and it works just fine for me. Just copy and paste the code from the link

Comment: I've put how I'm coding this in my main question above.  I've put the function in the report properties "Code" section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169449/discussion-between-craig-and-harry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks,  I found a link on a webpage that said: "VB code is no more supported in AX2012-SSRS".  Obviously this is why the PageNumber() function does not work for us.  However, using Harry's suggestion of moving our header fields into the body of the report fixed our issue and we no longer have two inches of blank white space on pages 2..x!  Thanks!

Comment: For me, it removes the header whitespace but creates a problem when exported the report as an excel file. Since the header doesn't remain fixed while scrolling down.